# Replacement rules in combination with pure functions to make a change of variables

Tags: differential-equations, symbolic, replacement, algebraic-manipulation, pure-function

I have defined my function in this way

```
w = f[r,Θ] ;
```

After some calculations i obtained my results with respect to the previous function. For instance:

```
Set[lapla1, -(1/(2 μ)) (1/r D[w r, {r, 2}] - 1/r^2 (D[w, {Θ, 2}] + Cot[Θ] D[w, {Θ, 1}]))] // ExpandAll
```

In this moment i don't need to work with the previous function $w$, instead i need to keep my previous result, multiply lapla1 by $r$ and work with a new $w$

```
w = f[r, Θ]/r ;
```

I'm trying to use pure functions to accomplish this, however i don't know if i'm proceeding correctly.

```
Set[lapla11,lapla1*r /. f -> (f[#, #2]/r &) // ExpandAll ]
```

**EDITED:**

When you make this transformation, the term $\frac{1 }{rμ }\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}$ must disappear from lapla1. This is the only way i found to prove it

```
Set[lapla12, -(r/(2 μ)) (1/r D[w/r r, {r, 2}] - 1/r^2 (D[w/r, {Θ, 2}] + Cot[Θ] D[w/r, {Θ, 1}]))] // ExpandAll
```

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly, an immediate solution would be use `SetDelayed` instead of `Set` in the expression `Set[lapla1, ...] // TrigExpand // ExpandAll`. Then when you change $w_1$ the change would reflect next time you evaluated `lapla1`. That said, this isn't a great way to write code - perhaps you should make `lapla1` a function of $w_1$. Also note that the single quote ' isn't a valid character for a variable name, assuming that's what you're going for in the last command.

Comment: @kuba I eliminated all subscripts and expressed my function in term of two variables instead of six.

Comment: I understand that you want to multiply lapla1 with (ra*rb) but 'protect" the terms including an 'f[]' from this multiplication. Your code works, except that you apply the replacement rule _outside_ the Set statement instead of _inside_. Same goes for the first use of _ExpandAll_.

Comment: @Wouter I can't exactly understand what you means with protect, at least in terms of code.

Comment: With 'protect from' I just mean 'but not multiply' the terms etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the term $\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}$ to disappear you need to introduce new function which would be:

```
w2 = f[r, θ] r
```

which means that you have to make a substitution `f -> w2/r`, this way:

```
lapla1 /. f -> (w2[#, #2]/# &) // Simplify // ExpandAll
```

> [image]

If you once used `f` or `w`, don't change theirs definitions, use a new one, you will less likely make a mistake.

Comment: is this what you're after?

Comment: The answer looks more easier than i thought.  Thank you very much @Kuba.

In order to get the result i was expecting, I didn't define a new variable, instead i use the previous one for w
`lapla1*r /. f -> (f[#, #2]/# &) // Simplify //  ExpandAll // TraditionalForm`
Regarding to your advise, in this case is ease to see the new definition, however i'll take it into account for future.